# Ubuntu 22.04 desktop computer would not boot due to mount issue

Tags: boot, grub2, usb, mount, dependencies

Regards, I misplaced the USB backup drive, I guess due to a dependent binding mount point, it would not boot. A message did appear....

```
(  13.098039) EXT4-fs (sdc1): VFS: Can't find ext4 filesystem
(  14.437082)
You are in emergency mode. After logging in type "Journalctl -xb"
 to view
system logs. "systemctl reboot" to reboot "systemctl default" or "exit"
to boot into default mode.
(or press Control-D to continue):​
```

Picked Control-D.....
Gave some kind of system check and revealed a funny looking prompt.    Couldn't remember all those code cmds so turned it off.

Found the backup USB plugged it in and the computer boots fine now. However, now concerned about this tiny USB shutting down machine. What if that USB were ever accidentally destroyed? Would like to know if there is a way to remove the hook from the system? Have some docs on the mounts if needed.

It is a Dell, Ubuntu 22.04

[image: /etc/fstab]

Note: possible chown, chmod "learning" error where ownership and control 'possibly' directed toward USB drive instead of mount point. Unaware of any recording options = no -(fstab.bak up). GUI installation of 3rd party mount bindings/hooks possible.

Comments from alt forum. Possible solution.
-unmounted the disk-- then I remounted it and Disks restored the original mount point of itself
-I found that by using the UUID of the drive as the mount point solves the issue.

-Update fix via PPA
[image: Bug Fix PPA]

Question not resolved by above attempts. UUID change, was not tried.

```
    # /etc/fstab: static file system information.
#
# Use 'blkid' to print the universally unique identifier for a
# device; this may be used with UUID= as a more robust way to name devices
# that works even if disks are added and removed. See fstab(5).
#
# <file system> <mount point>   <type>  <options>       <dump>  <pass>
# / was on /dev/sda5 during installation
UUID=8256fca0-2723-4e9a-bc64-ac669b1cdd7d   /                   ext4   errors=remount-ro>
# /boot/efi was on /dev/sda2 during installation
UUID=A9EF-3FF7                              /boot/efi           vfat   umask=0077       >
/swapfile                                   none                swap   sw               >
/dev/sda1                                   /mnt/SSD2           ext4   defaults         >
/dev/sdg1                                   /media/unity/sdg1   ext4   defaults         >

                                    [ Read 14 lines ]
```

Will boot/shut down with any USB with ext4 format.
Hook still there. Have sample of the suspected "hook", if requested.

Comment: It's possibly you've tagged the USB-external drive as *mandatory* for your systems boot, ie. I'd start by checking your systems *file-system table* (`/etc/fstab`) and see how you mounted it, did you record it as necessary? via options? or not  Adding that line (*if it's there & my thinking is correct*) to your question may help, though you may have used GUI or other tools to mount it too.

Comment: /etc/fstab content added to question.

Comment: Pictures of text are hard to read (*glare/contrast etc*) so sorry I'll move on to other questions. Making it easy for those trying to help can be useful you know.

Comment: fstab entered with code block.

Comment: When you add an external drive to `fstab` you should use the `nofail`-option so your system will boot even if the drive is not connected.

Comment: Added nofail -option to fstab the machine is working.

Comment: If you’ve solved it, rather than editing your question to say solved, please consider answering your own question separately.

Comment: Will do.... was wondering about how that was done.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Answered by mook765** -*adding the "nofail" option to the fstab on the /dev/sdg1 fixed the problem.*
Note: uninstalled errant programs mount hook is still there, the "nofail" option is a effective correction.

*possible update after UUID change*

After searching for some time, the solution was simple, the error was in fstab out of the immediate viewing area.

Answer: There are two ext4 partitions on the systems SSD one with root system and the other for file storage ext4 called SSD2 @ /dev/sda1. Then the external USB ext4 drive sdg1. In fstab in the SSD2 @ /dev/sda1 has a entry that was out of viewing area and there was the hook > /mnt/sdg1. That is the second user and why it insisted on a password to safely remove and for USB sdg1 be attached to boot and shutdown. I simply removed /mnt/sdg1 out of the /dev/sda1 SSD2 line, and it fixed the problem.

```
/dev/sda1 /mnt/SSD1 ext4 defaults 00 > ***/mnt/sdg1***
```

/dev/sdg1 ***UUID*** /mnt/sdg1 ext4 default 00

Comment: Please don't put SOLVED in the question title. Click on the gray check ✔️ mark next to your answer and turn it green ✅. This marks the question solved in this site.